# Control sound button in different scene action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq2Cl.png)

I've file fla with 2 scenes, in scene 1 I made a movie clip that have two button (in frame 1 is onSound button and in frame 2 is offSound button).
the button in movie clip can control the background musik (play and pause). 
And I copied that movie clip to scene 2.
I run the file and when I press button onSound the music stop and go to frame 2 (show the offSound button), but when I go to scene 2 with navigation button, the movie clip back to position when it show onSound button.

How can I make the movie clip don't back to first position (frame 1) when I move to the next scene?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're going at this the ideal way but in keeping with your setup: Try adding code to the button or the scene on scene 2 that detects what the current state of the sound is. So if on scene 1 the sound is turned off you set a global variable to false in that scene (i.e. isSoundOn = false). Then your button on scene 2 should look at that variable to see which frame / state it should display.